# Change font color in NSTableHeader

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

How can I change font color in header of `NSTableView`?

In Xcode Interface Builder - any color modifications in `Font Panel` of `Table  Column` properties are ignored / discarded.
Also I can not find a proper information my problem in Apple documentation.

Does anyone know is it possible ?

Answer (score 4):

For each of the `NSTableColumns` in the `[NSTableView tableColumns]`, do:

```
[[yourColumn headerCell] setAttributedStringValue:yourNSAttributedString].
```

The font color will be keyed to `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` in your string attribute dictionary.